# How to put a background image BEHIND the container, that fills the screen

Tags: html, css, background

I just started my account and I made a simple website for my first school project ( not at school yet but this was something I needed to do for some reason ).

So I got this Website all in a container wich is 900px wide.
That all works fine but now I got the ugly white spaces on the left, right and bottom part of the screen.
I wanna fill those up with a background image.

So far what I've done is putting the image there via the css document and it looks like this:

```
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, Sans-serif;
background: url(images/bos.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
```

The problem unfortunatly is that it now shows the background, fills the page. Then put my container underneath it and just adds another background picture there?

I've made a screenshot that might clarify something.
( Dont mind the ugly banner picture etc, that was practice and the background is the start of making it all look nice together )

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMOJl.jpg

I think it has something to do with the position being static or absolute or something..

Thanks for reading!
Hope to see a response fairly soon ;)

Cheers
-Jorrick

Comment: please share the html bud

Comment: @Jorrick - Why don't you replicate it on something like http://jsfiddle.net/, then click save, and add the link to your question? That way we can see what you've done, and suggest some corrections? Welcome to StackOverflow btw! :)

Comment: Well basicly because I cannot add all the maps I use? So links wont work etc. but here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/Ld8u6f8r/

Comment: Hey Jorric, could you like add random online image links in your fiddle's  CSS and img tag in HTML, so that images can be seen, Im still trying to understand what you want to achieve

Comment: Hey man, really appriciate you looking into this. That jsfiddle is really messing with my head since I am really new to this. Baiscly what I want is the following: I have a container, inside the container I got everything nice and sorted. Now because the container is only 900 px wide it got white space on left and right ( default white blank page background) I want to change the background of the website. And put my container ON TOP of that. Right now it loads the background image.. and shoves my container to the bottom. So its like I need to float the container on top of the background.